# Densities with Frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, statsmodels, seaborn

The two plots below convey roughly the same information.

- The one on the left is a histogram where the Y axis represents frequencies (i.e. how often we see values within the range associated with each bin).
- The one on the right is a density (KDE estimation). The Y axis represents density (the integral should add up to one).

I typically prefer the density plot (you can adjust the  but the Y axis is usually harder to interpret.

I know that KDE estimation would return a density that adds up to 1 assuming that the domain of the variable spans from -Inf to Inf, but is there any way to map the PDF resulting from KDE estimation to frequencies (e.g. scaling up the values to have frequencies)?

Is it just a matter of "scaling" of the axis? Or is there anything else involved?

[image: density vs frequency]

Comment: I haven't used density plots in matplotlib before; however, you could achieve something like what you describe with either a transformation or with twinx() -- see [http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html)

Comment: this possible with `seaborn` directly. see: http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/distplot_options.html

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to calculate density points first, and then plot. Read http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html. Some code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# This X is your data for the histogram
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)

kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=1).fit(X)
x = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 100).reshape(-1, 1)

density = np.exp(kde.score_samples(x))

plt.plot(x, density)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am confused. Why is your Y axis negative? Shouldn't the integral add up to 1?

Comment: Yes, I was looking into it: you must exp everypoint. Editing! Credit to http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/cs109/content/blob/master/lec_03_statistical_graphs.ipynb

Comment: Thanks! I guess that what's still missing is how to scale this to have it represent frequencies (as stated in the OP). I wonder if a simple `1/density` would do it?

Comment: I guess you can "deconvolve" (is that a word?) frequency to raw data very easy. Supose you have {"A": 0.6, "B": 0.3, "C": 0.1}. You can get ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"] from that if you know the total number of cases, and represent the density.